# google calendar java api

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have an object of CalendarEntry

I know that **http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/example@gmail.com/allcalendars/full** is the feed url of all calendars

but how I can get this feed url from CalendarEntry instance?

Because I wanna post a new entry in a specified calendar and I need this url.

Thanks!

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to specify that URL in your code like the following snippet:

```
CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("CalendarService");
myService.setUserCredentials("example@gmail.com", "yourPassword");
URL feedUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full");
CalendarFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl, CalendarFeed.class);
System.out.println("Your calendars:");
for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
  CalendarEntry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);
  System.out.println("\t" + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
}
```

CalendarEntry instances will store every calendars (primary, secondary,imported calendars) retrieved by the specified URL.

Comment: But how do I get the feed URL for the particular CalendarEntry instance? pccCalendar.getEditLink().getHref() doesn't work.

Comment: pccCalendar.getEditLink().getHref() will not work unless your calendar has been set as being publicly accessible (I think)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to do this:

```
public static URL toCalendarFeedURL(CalendarEntry calendarEntry) {
    try {
        String cal = "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds" + calendarEntry.getEditLink().getHref().substring(63) + "/private/full";
        return new URL(cal);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Curse Google for their diabolically confusing calendar APIs.